# how to add multiple values to an object array

Tags: c#, arrays, object

What is a quicker/shorter way to do this.

```
        Store[] store = new Store[3];

        store [0] = new Store();
        store [0].Price = 5.24;
        store [0].ValueType = eValueType.Normal;

        store [1] = new Store();
        store [1].Price = 7.89;
        store [1].ValueType = eValueTyp.Normal;

        store [2] = new Store();
        store [2].Price = 7.89;
        store [2].ValueType = eValueTyp.Normal;




public class Store
{
    public enum eValueType
    {
        Real,
        Normal
    }

    private double _price;
    private eValueType _valueType;

    public double Price
    {
        get { return _price; }
        set { _price = value; }
    }

    public eValueType ValueType
    {
        get { return _valueType; }
        set { _valueType = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about working code.  Consider posting it on Code Review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use object initializers, like this:

```
store[0] = new Store() { Price = 5.24, ValueType = eValueType.Normal };
store[1] = new Store() { Price = 7.89, ValueType = eValueType.Normal };
store[2] = new Store() { Price = 7.89, ValueType = eValueType.Normal };
```

Or if you provide a constructor to your `Store` class like this:

```
public Store (double price, eValueType valueType)
{
    this.Price = price;
    this.eValueType = valueType;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
store[0] = new Store(5.24, eValueType.Normal);
store[1] = new Store(7.89, eValueType.Normal);
store[2] = new Store(7.89, eValueType.Normal);
```

On a side note, you should probably use [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) instead of [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx) if you're trying to represent currency values.

Answer (score 1):

```
var stores = new []
    {
        new Store { Price = 5.24, ValueType = eValueType.Normal },
        new Store { Price = 7.89, ValueType = eValueType.Normal },
        new Store { Price = 7.89, ValueType = eValueType.Normal }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var stores = (new[] { 5.24, 7.89, 7.89 })
             .Select(p => new Store{ Price = p, ValueType = eValueType.Normal })
             .ToArray();
```

Or if you have different "ValueTypes" as well:

```
var prices = new[] { 3.12, 6.34, 7.89 };
var values = new[] { eValueType.Normal, eValueType.Real, eValueType.Real };
var stores = prices.Zip(values, 
                 (p, v) => new Store { Price = p, ValueType = v })
                 .ToArray();
```

Comment: This is the most clever solution based on the samples given IMO.  It breaks if a valuetype is ever not normal obviously, but a great solution. +1

Comment: @paqogomez Thanks for the comment, added a suggestion for different ValueTypes.